# Guidance for dircet migration from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2019

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, migration, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

I have a business requirement to migrate Existing SharePoint 2010 site to SharePoint 2019 directly. Request you to provide guidance on this. Also let me know what all challenges will be there.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upgrade scenario has not changed in SharePoint Server 2019. There is no direct upgrade path from SP 2010 to SP 2019.

To upgrade to SharePoint Server 2019, you must upgrade SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint Server 2013, then upgrade to SharePoint Server 2016, and finally upgrade to SharePoint Server 2019. Your databases must be at a SharePoint Server 2016 RTM version or higher when you upgrade to SharePoint Server 2019. Any database with a lower version will be locked and upgrade will not start.
(Microsoft supported upgrade path is DB Attach method for Site Collections)

There is no way to do this skipping a version unless you use a Third Party Migration tool like:

```
1. Sharegate

2. Metalogix

3. AvePoint
```

Answer (score 2):

Their is no OOTB direct way to migrate the from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2019. You can use 3rd party tools which will do direct migration for you. There are couple of them i.e. Sharegate or metalogix or etc

But if you want in house then you need SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2016 farm in between to migrate the database from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2019.

> SharePoint 2010 --> Upgrade DB in SharePoint 2013 --> Upgrade DB In
>   SharePoint 2016 --. Upgrade DB in SharePoint 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Out of experience. Don't do it. Set up a clean SP2019 and migrate date using something like sharegate. It will never work a 100%.

And only migrating data will be a great opportunity to clean house.